# How do I fix this exception when including a button in XAML in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to XAML and Xamarin and want to build a test app on my android device. On the first page there's a button that directs to an other page. Here's a piece of the C# code HomePage.xaml.cs:

```
public void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    Navigation.PushModalAsync (new SecondPage ());
}
```

On the second page I want to load an image and a button, but as soon as I include the button, I get this exception when running the app: `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`. Without the button, everything works fine. Here is the xaml code of the image and the button of the second page:

```
<Image  Source = "image.png" 
            x:Name="image"
            VerticalOptions="Start">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="ImageTapped"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
<Button Text="Text"
            BackgroundColor="Aqua"
            TextColor="White"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
```

And here the C# code of the "ImageTapped" function:

```
public void ImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    image.IsVisible = false;
}
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong and I would really appreciate it if somebody could me!

Comment: What is the  error message that exception gives? Post the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by using a `<StackLayout></StackLayout>`, before I used the `<ContentPage.Content>`.

Comment: FYI In Xamarin.Forms, page should contains only one View.But upside case trying to add 2 View which is wrong. Using a container like Grid, StackLayout, RelativeLayout, AbsoluteLayout could fix that issue(View could have more than one child).